# mysql server not starting after change my.cnf

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I wanted change my host in mysql on Ubuntu 14.04, so I checked /etc/init.d/mysql restart, server started. I changed /etc/mysql/my.cnf the line with bind-address = 127.0.0.1 to server Ip, then restart failed, when I change it back to 127.0.0.1 server can't start

**Solution**

```
# service mysql stop
# service mysql start
# service mysql restart
```